# Url privacy policy not working on Facebook developers

Tags: firebase

[When I click at sign icon the error show this what Ishould to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sDGc.jpg)

Comment: I try to create many url privacy but all of them not working

Comment: My goal is to create app android sign with facebook using firebase authentication facebook